# Windows Explorer crashing all the time

Tags: c#, window, explorer, windows-explorer

i getting a problem with the windows explorer. Every morning everything is perfect. I'm starting Visual Studio and develop some stuff.

After a while if i start my huge Project the Windows Explorer begins to crash all the time. For example if i right click on the Trash or Desktop or copy Files. Its just the normal, Send - Not Send, Windows Error Message.

I googled alot and found answers about the Windows Context Menu. But our Software don't add Entries to the Windows Context Menu.

Maybe it is Active Sync?

Its the only thing we are using in our Software.

Please can somebody help me? Our Customers got the same Problem and it is so annoying.

Comment: Are you using some refrrences in your project like Jquery etc.?

Comment: Not a programming question - check/disable other Browser Helper Objects also installed in IE.

Comment: @stephbu not IE. Iam talking about the Windows Explorer.

Comment: @dilipkumbham like your comment? iam doing my best with my english.

Comment: BHOs are loaded into both IE and Explorer processes and can impact both.  Other than the registry, IExplore is one of the few places where you can which BHOs are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lexli/archive/2009/08/23/when-the-application-program-crashes-on-windows.aspx

Windows Explorer is still a Windows application, so debugging it can tell you why it crashes (at least because of which module it crashes). Then you can search on the Internet to see how to get rid of that problematic module.

Comment: i tried this before. but its throwing so much exceptions that there is no possible way to continue my work. and the "funny" thing is, if i attach the debugger, the explorer dont want to crash anymore.

Comment: I assume that you used WinDbg to attach to explorer.exe based on your description. Unless you are an expert of it, don't use it. Debug Diag and ADPlus.exe in fact only monitor crashes. They won't block your other activities within Windows Explorer. Crash dumps will be generated when that process crashes, and then you can use WinDbg to analyze the crash dumps.